# Higher-order function

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I have an exercise about JavaScript. This exercise requires me to use higher-order functions. I have managed to specify some of the functions so far, but when I try to execute the code, the result does not seem to work properly. I have some images to give you an idea, hopefully, you can help me correct this.

- The thread is: **Write the function loop(loops, number, func), which runs the given function the given number of times. Also write the simple functions halve() and square().**
- This is my code:

```js
function loop(loops, number, func) {
  var loops = function(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (i < 0) {
        console.log('Programme ended')
      }
      if (i > 0) {
        return n;
      }
    }
  }
}

var halve = function(n) {
  return n / 2
}

var square = function(n) {
  return n ** 2;
}

console.log(halve(50));
console.log(loop(5, 200, halve));
console.log(loop(3, 5, square));
console.log(loop(-1, 99, halve));
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? What doesn't work? How are you calling the function?

Comment: The code in the question and the code in the image are significantly different. The code in the question is not syntactically correct as a start.

Comment: @VLAZ The code in the post and in the picture they are the same, I just missed edit the code when copy the code from the picture and paste it to the post so you can try it out.

Comment: @nsuspect [you shouldn't really be posting images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Just stick to something we can easily work with.

Comment: @Bergi The grey part is not suppose to be tempted with, I can only write the code above it and the system will automatically evaluate it for me, I managed to get the HALVE function working, but when it came to calling HALVE function in LOOP function it says Undefined

Comment: @VLAZ Ah, sorry, let me edit the post.

Comment: @PeterSeliger You're not wrong, I should have just written "Higher-order function".

Comment: What are you expecting as output? The `loop` function just defines a variable named `loops` (overwriting the argument named the same) and exits. By default any function that exits without running a `return` statement returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so first things first: Higher-Order functions are functions that work on other functions.
The reason why you get undefined is because you are calling a function which doesn't return anything.

```
function x(parameter){
  result = parameter + 1;
}
// -> returns undefined every time
console.log(x(5));
// -> undefined
function y(parameter){
  return parameter+1;
}
// -> returns a value that can be used later, for example in console.log
console.log(y(5));
// -> 6
```

Second, you are using n for your *for loop* when you should probably use *loops* so it does the intended code as many times as "loops" indicates instead of the number you insert (i.e. 200, 5, 99).

By having the "console.log" inside a loop you may get a lot of undesired "programme ended" in your output so in my version I kept it out of the loop.

The other two answers given are pretty complete I believe but if you want to keep the *for loop* here goes:

```
function loop(loops, number, func){
  if(loops>0){
    for(let i = 0; i< loops; i++){     // let and const are the new ES6 bindings (instead of var)
      number = func(number)
    }
    return number
  }
  else{
    return "Programme ended"
  }
}

function halve(n) {     // maybe it's just me but using function declarations feels cleaner
    return n / 2;
}
  
function square(n) {    
    return n ** 2;
}

console.log(halve(50));
console.log(loop(5, 200, halve));
console.log(loop(3, 5, square));
console.log(loop(-1, 99, halve));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current `loop` function declares an inner function and then exits. Ie, nothing actually happens -

```
function loop(loops,number,func){

    // declare loops function
    var loops= function(n){
         // ...
    }

    // exit `loop` function
}
```

One such fix might be to run the supplied `func` a number of times in a `for` loop, like @code_monk suggest. Another option would be to use recursion -

```js
function loop (count, input, func) {
  if (count <= 0)
    return input
  else
    return loop(count - 1, func(input), func)
}

function times10 (num) {
  return num * 10
}

console.log(loop(3, 5, times10))
// 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```js
const loop = (loops, n, fn) => {
  for (let i=0; i<loops; i++) {
    console.log( fn(n) );
  }
};


const halve = (n) => {
  return n / 2;
};

const square = (n) => {
  return n ** 2;
};

loop(2,3,halve);

loop(4,5,square);
```

Comment: Adding explanation of code is typically a good idea, especially when the OP is a newcomer to the language.